# Where does one find pair-correlation functions for various materials?

Tags: resource-recommendations, material-science, atomic-physics, correlation-functions, data

What is the canonical source for finding pair-correlation functions for atoms in various materials? I am interested in both numeric computations and experimental measurements (like might be obtained from neutron scattering). Is a free source available?

Comment: Side question: what characteristic atomic length does the greek sigma refer to on the x-axis of plots of pair-correlations functions, e.g. figure 2 here: http://www.ou.edu/mms/Publications/HAWA/2008_Langmuir_henz.pdf

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a book recommendation question. Concerning whether book recommendation questions are on-topic or not, see various discussions on our meta site.

Comment: @Qmechanic: This is not a request for a textbook recommendation, but for a data source.  If someone asked "How do I find the lifetimes of unstable particles" and the answer is "The Particle Data Group's Review of Particle Physics", would this be off topic?  This has nothing to do with StackExchange, or even with teaching physics in general, so I can't see how it's meta.  It's about practicing physics.

Comment: The [tag:books] tag also covers data sources, cf. the [wiki tag description (v6)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/books/info).

Comment: @Qmechanic: The books tag is for Physics.SE proper, not meta.  I'm not disputing the tag, I'm disputing this being closed as off-topic.

Comment: Right. On the meta site, the Phys.SE community e.g. makes policies of what is on- and off-topic on the main site.

Comment: Yes, so your comment about tagging this as "books" doesn't help explain why you think this is off-topic.  I've read several of the meta discussions, and none of them seem authoritative or to specifically exclude this.  How do you answer my question about the PDG?  How would I rephrase this question to figure out how in the hell to get this type of data?  Do you really think the reasonable Physics.SE policy of preventing open-ended discussion of textbooks should be construed to prevent someone from asking a question here on how to find *any* such data source as I've described?

Comment: Since OP appears to (i) be a professional in academia; (ii) the request for data source appears to be part of a high-end research-level project; and (iii) he has presumably done his homework on beforehand and already checked various sources himself with no luck, I have decided to reopen this question as a test-case of such type of questions.